# Removing old DKMS files fails due to new kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, apt

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 and due to some problems with the linux kernel 5.3 i switched to 5.4. Now if i want to remove old virtualbox dkms files (virtualbox-6.0.14), dpkg exits with error code 10. Can someone help me? I attached the output of apt autoremove here:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.0.14-dfsg-1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.0.14 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.0.14
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.0.14 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.21-20.02.19.amdgpu.ubuntu
Building initial module for 5.4.21-20.02.19.amdgpu.ubuntu
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.4.21-20.02.19.amdgpu.ubuntu is not     supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.21-20.02.19.amdgpu.ubuntu (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.0.14/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit     status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could remove the package with:

```
sudo apt remove --force-yes virtualbox-dkms
```